# Cadastro único de usuário e senha convertendo mysql_* para PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso atualizar um código legado e para isso preciso fazer duas modificações nele.

A primeira modificação é abandonar as funções `mysql_*` e utilizar o PDO.

A segunda é atualizar o banco de modo que eu não consiga cadastrar dois nomes de usuário e senha com os mesmos valores.

Código que busca o `Nome` e `imgPerfil` de um usuário:

```
<?php 

require_once "includes/config.php";

$Usuario = $_SESSION["Usuario"];
$Senha   = $_SESSION["Senha"];

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Nome, imgPerfil FROM administradores WHERE Usuario=$Usuario' AND Senha='$Senha' ");
```

Código que pega os valores do usuário:

```
<?php 

while($Linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)) {
    $nomeUser = $Linha['Nome'];
    $imgpUser = $Linha['imgPerfil'];
}
```

Código que imprime os valores:

```
<?php echo $nomeUser; ?>
```

e

```
<?php echo $imgpUser; ?>
```

Comment: Não consigo entender a pergunta.

Comment: Este tutorial mostra como usar PDO, incluindo Prepared Statements: http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/como-usar-pdo-com-banco-de-dados-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para evitar valores duplicados defina a coluna como unique key direto pelo banco.

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (campo)
```

Para converter o código com o PDO e prepared statements

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste',$usuario_db, $senha_db);

$sql = 'SELECT Nome, imgPerfil FROM administradores 
        WHERE Usuario= :usuario AND Senha =:senha';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario);
$stmt->bindValue(':senha', $senha);

$stmt->execute();
$item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //retorna apenas uma linha
echo $item['Nome'] .' - '. $item['imgPerfil'];
```