# Problemas com PHP 5.2

Tags: php

Eu fiz uma pagina de *Admin* para um site e quando eu subi no servidor descobri que a versão do PHP é a 5.2 e não tem como eu atualizar, o *server* sempre me apresenta *error* na função `mysql_fetch_array()`, eu gostaria de saber se tem uma função equivalente para o php 5.2 e se o PDO poderia resolver meu problema?

Esse é o código que eu fiz:

```
$selecao = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nome_table WHERE nivel = 'Cliente' 
                        ORDER BY nome_contato"); 

while ($selecao_dados = mysql_fetch_array($selecao)) { 

    echo $id = base64_encode($selecao_dados['id_user']); 

}
```

O erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que PDO resolveria, mas seu seu código não poderemos saber, assim como mutley disse, porém também achei um tópico sobre esse assunto -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004500/is-mysql-fetch-array-supported-in-php-5-2-6

Comment: Você poderia disponibilizar algum código para que a gente ajudasse, também.

Comment: <?php

$selecao = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nome_table WHERE nivel = 'Cliente' ORDER BY nome_contato");

while ($selecao_dados = mysql_fetch_array($selecao)) { 
       
echo $id = base64_encode($selecao_dados['id_user']);

}

?>

Comment: Relacionado: [Atualizar código antigo para PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45136/91)

Comment: Faça [edit] a pergunta e coloque lá o código.

Comment: http://meutema.hol.es/img/error.PNG

Comment: Esse erro significa que a consulta falhou, é provavel o valor de `nivel` veio em branco.

Comment: Na linha do `mysql_query`, no lugar do `;` coloque esse código, `or die(mysql_error());` e veja se aparece outro erro.

Comment: Da uma olhada que pode ser o mesmo problema que o seu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004500/is-mysql-fetch-array-supported-in-php-5-2-6

Answer (score 1):

Tente modificar seu código para algo como:

```
$querySQL = 'SELECT * FROM tabela_usuario WHERE id = 1234';
$query = mysql_query($querySQL);

if (!($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)))
{
    echo 'Usuário não encontrado!';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        var_dump($row);
    echo 'Usuário encontrado!';
}
```

Testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente(PHP VERSION 5.6.3), precisando adaptações claro, para sua necessidade... no caso do SQL;

Comment: esse é o problema o meu script funciona bem a partir da versão 5.3 mas na 5.2 que é a versão que esta no servidor ele me apresenta diversos erros, eu até tentei ver na documentação do PHP se tinha alguma função equivalente ao mysql_fetch_array() mas não encontrei nada.

Comment: Você alterou seu código para o descrito acima e testou?

Comment: Sim eu alterei, e ele apresentou os mesmos erros na função mysql_fetch_array().

Comment: Troque seu mysql_query por isso aqui => mysql_query($query)or die( mysql_error() ); e nos informe se aconteceu algum erro.

Comment: Pessoal muito obrigado pela ajuda, acabei de resolver o problema, foi um error nas configurações do meu banco de dados, agora já está tudo correto.

Comment: @mikaellemos033 Edite sua pergunta e coloque como resolveu seu problema, assim caso aconteça alguma coisa com os comentários, a solução não será perdida.