# Proibir e-mails duplicados no MySQL usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**Minha situação é a seguinte**, tenho um sistema de e-mail marketing todo em PHP e os emails são adicionados por arquivo .CSV, porém ele está adicionando valores duplicados e valores em branco.

**O problema é que**, eu tenho 1 tabela chama `n_emails` com 2 colunas, uma chamado `ativo` e outra `email`, a coluna `ativo` tem e deve ter valores duplicados, porque vai ser ela que vai dizer se o email está ativo ou não, ou seja, em praticamente todos os emails o valor da coluna `ativo` vai ser `s`. A unica parte que eu quero que seja proibido os valores duplicados vai ser na coluna `email`.

**Resumindo,** preciso bloquear somente e-mails duplicados e e-mails em branco e no fim, após adicionar o arquivo .CSV, o sistema mostra a contagem de registros adicionados e registros não adicionados (no caso os e-mails duplicados).

**Código em que adiciona os e-mails está assim:**

```
 }

 $tabela = "n_emails";
 $arquivo = 'addemail/x234gqq.csv';

 $arq = fopen($arquivo,'r');

 while(!feof($arq))
 for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
 if ($conteudo = fgets($arq)){
 $ll++; // $ll 
 $linha = explode(';', $conteudo);// 
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela (ativo, email) VALUES 
 ('$linha[0]', '$linha[1]')";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $linha = array();
 }
 echo "Quantidade de Emails Adicionados: ".$ll; 
 echo "<br><a href='..'>Clique aqui para voltar</a>";

 ?>
```

Comment: Coloque a coluna `email` como [unique key](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45139/91) no banco de dados.

Comment: é só rodar `ALTER TABLE n_emails ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (email)` no próprio phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Em teoria sim e essa coluna não pode ter nenhum valor duplicado, caso contrario vc vai precisar remover eles antes de aplicar a modificação.

Comment: Funcionou, mas ao carregar ele mostra uma tela de erro e eu gostaria que aparecesse por exemplo, Emails Duplicados: {n} Emails Adicionados: {n}, como eu poderia fazer isso @rray ?

Comment: Vai precisar de dois contadores um para os inserts de sucesso e outro para os de falha, use a função `mysql_query()` no if para saber se o insert funcinou ou não, claro vai precisar de mais alguns ajustes, a ideia basica é essa.

Comment: Ao invés de fazer uma estripulia no banco pra ter esse comportamento, por que não alterar a aplicação pra fazer um `select` antes de mandar o `insert` pro banco? Trata-se de um sistema com um baixo volume de dados, correto? Nesse caso 2 querys não vão afetar o desempenho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Garanta a unicidade do valor pelo banco de dados, adicionando uma constraint unique key dessa forma o banco é responsável por saber qual valor é repetido ou não.

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (coluna)
```

Para mostrar a contagem de registro inseridos, verifique o resultado de `mysql_query()` e faça o incremento respectivo contador(`$sucesso` ou `$falha`)

```
$sucesso = 0;
$falha = 0;
while(!feof($arq)){
    for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
        if($conteudo = fgets($arq)){
            $ll++; // $ll 
            $linha = explode(';', $conteudo);// 
        }

        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO $tabela (ativo, email) VALUES  ('%s', '%s')", $linha[0], $linha[1]);
        if(mysql_query($sql)){
           $sucesso++;
        }else{
           $falha++;
        }
        $linha = array();
    }
    echo "Resumo: Emails duplicados: $falha. Emails Adicionados: $sucesso";
    echo "<br><a href='..'>Clique aqui para voltar</a>";
}
```

Comment: Ocorreu tudo certo, sem bugs e falhas, valeu @rray era tudo que eu tava querendo e não estava conseguindo haha

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar uma pre-validação no php e também adicionar unique como citado pelo @rray,

Esta pre-validação pode ser elaborada com um array_unique() e alguma condição validando se o email é diferente de vazio e ativo esta igual a `s`.

**Exemplo foo.csv:**

```
foo@gmail.com;s
bar@gmail.com;s
qux@gmail.com;s
bar@gmail.com;s
;s
foobar@gmail.com;
```

**Validando:**

```
function getCSV($name) {
   $file = fopen($name, "r");
   $result = array();
   $i = 0;
   while (!feof($file)):
      if (substr(($result[$i] = fgets($file)), 0, 10) !== ';;;;;;;;') :
         $i++;
      endif;
   endwhile;
   fclose($file);
   return $result;
}

function getLine($array, $index) {
   return explode(';', $array[$index]);
}

$foo = getCSV('foo.csv');
$foo = array_unique($foo); // remove os repetidos
for ($i = 0; $i < count($foo); $i++) {
   $line = getLine($foo, $i);
   if (!empty($line[0]) && trim($line[1]) == 's') { // válida se tem valor e é ativo.
      print_r($line); // faça os insert's aqui
   }
}
```

**Saída:**

```
Array ( [0] => foo@gmail.com [1] => s ) Array ( [0] => bar@gmail.com [1] => s ) Array ( [0] => qux@gmail.com [1] => s )
```

Comment: Agora ele não está mais adicionando os e-mails nem no Mysql

Comment: @VictorGomes tentou debugar para ver onde ele para?

Comment: Funcionou certo, era erro meu desculpe, obrigado @GabrielRodrigues, sua ajuda contou muito amigo, espero que ajude outros membros do Stack também